# how to use span to call in android?

Tags: android

i have a textview whose text i am setting as a big string.

this string has several parts like telphone no, mail , browsing address.

i have found how to use the browsing address in a span to open up the link in a browser?
here is the code

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infotest);
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.clientaddress));

    ss.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://"+getResources().getString(R.string.clientaddress)), 0, 23,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

how do i do the same for telephone text.
i mean how do i span the telephone text to call a the number when the user presses that specific part of the textview string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it from the xml file.

For example:

android:id="@+id/mobile_number"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:autoLink="phone"

Available values for the autoLink field is: web, email, phone, map, all

Comment: In case you have a textview with a phone number..You want when the user click on the textview to call the number right?So, you have to add this attribute to your textview at the xml file: android:autoLink="phone"..

Comment: once i have put it this way in code, i do not need to code anything in java? also this does not solve my problem, i just want a part of a string to do phone calling

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html)?

```
Linkify.addLinks(tv,Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

ETA or try using tel:// instead of http?